# Find optimal configuration ranges for manufacturing process

Tags: optimization, unsupervised-learning

Let's assume I have some industrial manufacturing process with one costs and a produced output as well as a number of variables to configure the process.

Based on my historic data I would like to find out what is the optimal range of var1, var2, var3 to produce my output with low costs (costs/unit). So I would like to find out e.g. var1 should be between 0.1-0.2, var2 0.8-1.0 and var3 0.2-0.3 for cheap production and which variables are most important for the optimization.

```
costs/unit      var1    var2    var3
20              0.5     0.1     0.12
19              0.4     0.2     0.13
15              0.4     0.1     0.16
10              0.1     0.9     0.23
23              0.5     0.3     0.24
```

The table above is just an example, in reality there are 50 variables and much more rows, but I just wanted to ask if you have some ideas which approach is the best for that requirement? Is it possible to use clustering therefore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You face with a regression problem. You can train a regression tree on your data, where the cost/unit is the label. The learned tree reflects the required knowledge. Each path starting from the root ending in one leaf shows a rule that reflect which variables have impact on the cost and how they influence the cost.

Comment: Okay thanks, but then how would I get the recommended ranges for my variables to produce with low costs?

Comment: Then you should select those leaves that their cost values are low. The paths associated with these leaves give the appropriate ranges for different variables. Your final rule is obtained by making the OR of these rules.